# Cannot load assets more than once with PreloadJS and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, createjs, preloadjs

I am trying to create a `Vue.js` component which would allow me to load (using `PreloadJS`) and display various `EaselJS` canvas experiments. The Vue.js component:

1. Gets created with a HTML canvas and 2 divs for experiment scripts
   and the `EaselJS` library
2. `created` lifecycle hook: Loads the `EaselJS` library using `PreloadJS`
   (included in the main HTML file)
3. Stores the `EaselJS` lib files in the `#creatjLib` div
4. Afterwards it loads the experiment script files and stores them in
   `#gameAssets`

Here is the component:

```
<template>
  <div class="fullscreen">
    <canvas id="canvas" class="fill"></canvas>
    <div id="createjsLib" class="hidden"></div>
    <div id="gameAssets" class="hidden"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {createjsList} from '../../assets/lists/games.js'
  import {manifests} from '../../assets/conf.js'

  export default {
    props: ['id'],
    data() {
      return {
        game: createjsList[this.id],
        queue: new createjs.LoadQueue()
      };
    },
    methods: {
      onLibrariesLoaded() {
        var lib = this.queue.getResult("EaselJS");
        var libCont = document.getElementById("createjsLib");
        libCont.innerHTML = "";
        libCont.appendChild(lib);

        document.getElementById('gameAssets').innerHTML = "";
        var manifest = (this.game.manifest) ? this.game.manifest : '/static/games/' + this.id + '/manifest.json';
        this.queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
        this.queue.on("complete", this.onGameAssetsLoaded);
        this.queue.on("fileload", this.onGameAssetLoaded);
        this.queue.loadManifest(manifest);
      },
      onGameAssetLoaded(e) {
        var type = e.item.type;
        if (type == createjs.LoadQueue.CSS || type == createjs.LoadQueue.JAVASCRIPT) {
          document.getElementById('gameAssets').appendChild(e.result);
        }
      },
      onGameAssetsLoaded() {
        console.log('Assets Loaded');
      }
    },
    created() {
      var manifest = manifests.createjs;
      this.queue.on("complete", this.onLibrariesLoaded);
      this.queue.loadManifest(manifest);
      console.log('created');
    }
  }
</script>
```

### The Problem

My problem is that this process only works once. I can load the `EaselJS` library and the experiments files only once, the scripts get correctly executed but once I navigate (`vue-router`, history mode) home for example and then back to the experiment it fails to even load the library again and crashes in the `created` lifecycle hook.

> Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'observeArray'
>   of undefined"

[image: Console log]

I tried using the `destroyed` and `beforeDestroy` lifecycle hooks to cancel, delete, reset the `PreloadJS` queue but nothing I tried works. The error seems to happend somewhere in Vue.js but I am not sure why or how to fix this. I have checked the manifest url and it points to the correct static `JSON` manifest file.

Any ideas what's going on? What have I missed here? Any advice/help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line: `queue: new createjs.LoadQueue()` is likely the culprit. Vue.js requires that all properties of its `data` object be primitive values or plain objects.

You can create an instance of `createjs.LoadQueue` inside your `created()` hook and save it to some internal property on your component. A common convention is to make it something like `this.$createjsQueue`. Up to you.

```
data() {
    return {
        game: createjsList[this.id],
        queue: null
    }
},
created() {
    this.$createJsQueue = new createjs.LoadQueue()

    // Expose some internal value of the instance
    this.queue = this.$createJsQueue._queue
}
```

Comment: Oh great answer thanks! I wasn't aware of the plain object constraint. The `PreloadJS` `complete` event object seems to actually store the queue reference in the `currentTarget` property so I decided to not store any reference at all. Thanks a lot :)